# Why <div> wrapping necessary in my AngularJS directive for Jquery UI autocomplete widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, angularjs, directive

Recently I tried to write a AngularJS directive to use with Jquery UI autocomplete widget.
The directive is used this way:

```
<input type="text" auto-comp ng-model="lan" />
```

It is supposed to function as as autocomplete widget, and stored the selected item to a model,  $scope.lan.

Finally I was successful, but find that I have to put a "div" tag wrapping the "input" tag, i.e.,

```
<div><input type="text" auto-comp ng-model="lang" /></div>
```

Without the "div" wrapping, Chrome will report an error:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined

The libraries used are:
jquery 1.8.3
jquery UI 1.9.2
angularjs 1.0.3

I uploaded the code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QSBvh/23/
You can remove the div, and see the result.

Below is the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('autoComp', function () {
       return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element).autocomplete({
                    source: scope.availableTags,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        scope.lan = ui.item.value;
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
        }
});
```

New finding. When I put .autocomplete inside a

```
scope.$watch("availableTags", function(value) {});
```

suddenly, the "div" wrapping is not needed. Very strange.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('autoComp', function () {
       return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("availableTags", function(value) {
                $(element).autocomplete({
                    source: scope.availableTags,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        scope.lan = ui.item.value;
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: It's just how AngularJS works. Using the children of the element with the attribute `ng-controller="ExCtrl"`

Comment: what is the difference between <div> and <input>, as the children of the element with the attribute ng-controller="ExCtrl"?

Comment: Just a guess, because it's not looking for `<input>`. Read the documentation. It should explain it.

Comment: Which part of the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The .autocomplete() is using the element parent and it is probably looking for a div parent in order to add to it the functionality.

Comment: Possible reason. However, I have a new finding. It turns out the div parent is not necessary after all. Very strange.